# Антивирусы удаляют exe файл после компиляции python кода в exe

Tags: python, python-3.x, антивирус

Есть небольшой проект, сделанный на python. Я его скомпилировал в exeшник, для того чтобы приложением могли пользоваться на других компьютерах где нет python'a. Однако антивирусы удаляют exe файл приложения после компиляции, говоря что это вирус, хотя программа таковым не является. Из-за чего это может быть и как это можно исправить?

Comment: А внести каталог, куда пишется этот файл, в исключения мысля не приходила? впрочем, какой смысл? всё равно его прибьёт антивирь на компе конечного пользователя.

Comment: Если вы там что-то скачиваете и записываете в файлы, то антивирусы могут на это дело параноить. Были недавно такие вирусы на питоне.

Comment: @CrazyElf а как это исправить?

Answer (score 2):

Ложноположительное срабатывание антивируса. У пайинсталера есть готовый кусок экзешника для сборки исполняемого файла. Так как этот проект ктото использовал  для написания вируса - он попал в базы и такая проблема у многих.

Попробуйте другую версию, а лучше пересоберите пайинсталер (понадобится msvc)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте:

1. Попробуйте изменить настройки компилятора
2. Попробуйте не использовать системные папки, изменения в реестре, подключения к портам или сайтам
3. Попробуйте использовать утилиты для шифрования вашего exe: DKMC  или сайт: freeobfuscator.com + enigma
4. Написать жалобу в администрацию
   Помните pyinstaller не совершенен, и когда я написал прогу и скомпилировал ее, то получил ошибку, хотя при тестировании все работало корректно.

Comment: обфускатор может оторвать прикрепленный zip